# How to find a SwiftUI view with custom tag or accessibility identifier?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit, introspection

Here's the sample code (using [Introspect](https://github.com/siteline/SwiftUI-Introspect) package):

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Introspect

struct ContentView: View {
    let tag = 123
    let id = "abc"

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Text("Hello, world!")
                .tag(tag)
                .accessibility(identifier: id)
        }.introspectScrollView { (scrollView) in
            /// - Note: find with tag
            if scrollView.viewWithTag(tag) != nil {
                print("OK")
            } else {
                print("NOT OK")
            }
            /// - Note: find with accessibilityIdentifier
            if findViewWithID(id, in: scrollView) != nil {
                print("OK")
            } else {
                print("NOT OK")
            }
        }
    }

    func findViewWithID(_ id: String, in uiView: UIView) -> UIView? {
        if uiView.accessibilityIdentifier == id {
            return uiView
        }
        for view in uiView.subviews {
            if let view = findViewWithID(id, in: view) {
                return view
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Why is `tag` or `accessibilityIdentifier` not propagated properly to the underlying view hierarchy?

Comment: Opposite question: why it should?

Comment: I understand that technically it's not the same view, but I kind of expected that to work since how else am I able to find a specific SwiftUI view in hierarchy in order to get its frame and perform a scroll without `ScrollViewReader` (in order to support iOS 13 too)?

Answer (score 2):

Anyway, workaround for this turned out to be quite simple:

- since "tagging" a view works just fine with UIKit view (even when wrapped in UIViewRepresentable) this simple wrapper comes to help:

```swift
struct TagView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let tag: Int

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
        let uiView = UIView()
        uiView.tag = tag
        return uiView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
        uiView.tag = tag
    }
}
```

- then instead of trying to tag SwiftUI view directly, we can just add it to a ZStack containing the previous wrapper of a tagged UIKit view, which can later be found in the view hierarchy using `viewWithTag(_:)`:

```swift
ZStack {
    TagView(tag: 123)
    Text("Hello, world!")
}
```

Comment: I'm really not sure if this is correct solutions, what if I 10s and 1000s of views being populated. Just curious to if there is any better way for this.

Comment: Using tags in UIKit is generally consider to be a poor practice and has performance hits behind the scenes. It's huge code smell and I wouldn't accept the above as an appropriate answer. UIKit tagging != SwiftUI tagging.

Comment: I agree that this is not the best solution, but it's the only one which I found for this particular use case (when you have to find some view in the SwiftUI hierarchy) so I just shared my solution. Case which this solved for me was to programatically scroll to a particular view with SwiftUI 1 (iOS 13) where there is no `ScrollViewReader` available.